# How much space to allocate to GCM registration ID

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How much space should I allocate on my database for the GCM registration ID?

I've seen talks with a lot of different guesses. Some are saying they've seen them as big as 205 chars, other saying 185 bytes and a discussion mentioned that it could be as large as 4k (it didn't specify if it was chars or bytes).

Does anyone have any best practices other than just reported sightings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4k bytes is an upper limit on the size of reg id. [It was mentioned somewhere by Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-gcm/q2PzJTP71TY/DNX4lvDu5X4J). The smaller lengths fly mentioned were observed by people experimenting with GCM.

To be safe, you should use a column type that can be as large as 4096 characters (or bytes, since reg id contains only alpha-numerical characters plus - and _). Such column is too large to create an index on, so for lookup purposes you probably want to create an additional smaller indexed column that will contain a hash value of the reg id.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, it seems there's no documentation at all.

Comment: @AskeG It was mentioned by a Google developer. See the link I added to the answer.